# Circumvent type system for casting a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, casting

C# won't let me cast a type `T` to a type I can prove `T` to be. How can I cast `T` to that type?

```
public static T _cast<T> (object o) {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) {
        return (T) o.ToString(); // Compiler YELLS!
    }
    throw new InvalidCastException("missing compiler generated case");
}
```

I'm writing a program that generates code from C++ to C#. This `_cast` operation I want to use in place of C++'s `operator T ()`.

Comment: That's not what I'd call a "cast".  The method only does something useful when T is String; otherwise just returns null or zero.  e.g. _cast(10) return 0.  That's astoundingly unclear and surprising to anyone using it.

Comment: I repeat: This is for computer generated code! Who cares if it is readable? But changing the `default(T)` to a throw would be better... so I'll do it.

Comment: Why on earth was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I don't answer my own questions, but I just came up with the solution: downcast to `object` before casting to `T`

```
public static T _cast<T> (object o) {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) {
        return (T)(object) o.ToString();
    }
    throw new InvalidCastException("missing compiler generated case");

}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer.   It's often referred to as a "double cast".  I (rarely) have had the need to do this too.

Answer (score 3):

I think a more elegant solution than your double cast is using the `as` keyword. Like this:

```
return o.ToString() as T;
```

I didn't try it, but the compiler shouldn't have an issue with that since it will return null when it can't cast the string to T, which within your conditional it won't do of course.

Comment: +1 useful approach when one can add `class` restriction for the template like `class MyTest<T> where T : class`. Otherwise you get compile error since `as` is not valid for value types.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov What a shame. I did not consider that. Thank you very much for pointing it out! Lemme hit you back! :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, are you sure?  I just tried it and it compiled fine:  `void M<T>(T t) { var s = t as string; }`

Comment: @KirkWoll what are your constraints on T? That is, in your class declaration, do you have any ``where T :` clause?

Comment: @Mithon, the example I gave is actually complete -- it's a method declaring a type parameter named `T` with no constraints.

Comment: @KirkWoll Ah, yes, I see it now. In your example s is of Type string, and the constraint on the as operator would be on the target not the source, so your code would compile, since string is a reference type and not a value type. In my answer however I'm doing as T. If T is let's say an int, then there's no null value available so when the first operand is not an int the operator can't return a null value, which defeats the purpose of the operator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no conversion from String to every other type.  The compiler is telling you it doesn't know how to do what you've asked.  If you provide more detail about what you're trying to do, maybe someone can offer some advice.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between casting and parsing. I think what you want is to try and parse strings

```
int stringToNum = (int)"123";  //will not compile

int stringToNum2 = int.Parse("123");
```

Comment: No, the OP is trying to cast an object that is *already* a string into a string (type `T`).